# Using Parameter and Bookmarks together in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SSRS 2016 Report with multiple tables on every pages. User should select a particular table in the parameter panel and jump to the page of this table. **Is it possible to do?**

I did not find any way to do it.

**Try:** I create a textbox with a Action to Bookmark and the expression of the Parameter Value but nothing happen. Tables also have their own Bookmark name.

ChatGPT tells me that is the way that work. But nothing happen. If I select a table in the parameter field i do not jump to the corresponding table.